# How can I rotate an svg on click and rotate back to its original version on another in JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, dom, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a simple accordion FAQ web component. Basically, **each question has an arrow next to it and the arrow will rotate 180 degrees when the question is open and rotate back when it is closed**. Questions will close on click or on click to another question.

I've mostly done what I aim but there is this problem that I can't really find a proper way to rotate back the arrows on close.
Here I will give the html markup the part of the JQuery scripts so you can have a solid reference(I've removed the unncesessary parts to avoid confusion. It originally has total of 5 questions.):

**HTML Markup:**

```
          <div class="containerDropdown">
            <p class="question">
              How many...?
              <svg class="arrow-down"...</svg>
            </p>
            <p class="answer">
              You can invite...
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="containerDropdown">
            <p class="question">
              What is...?
              <svg class="arrow-down"...</svg>
            </p>
            <p class="answer">
              No more than 2GB...
            </p>
          </div>
```

**JQuery Scripts:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const questions = $(".question");
  const answers = $(".answer");
  const arrows = $(".arrow-down");

  questions.click(function () {
    let question = $(this);
    let answer = question.siblings(".answer");
    let arrow = question.children(".arrow-down");

    answers.not(answer).hide(500);
    answer.toggle(500);

    if (arrow.hasClass("rotate-180")) {
      arrows.not(arrow).removeClass("rotate-180");

      arrow.removeClass("rotate-180");
    } else {
      arrows.not(arrow).removeClass("rotate-180");
      arrow.addClass("rotate-180");
    }
  });
});
```

What I've tried to do up there is an unefficient(I think so) way of toggleClass(). I **couldn't create an algorithm with toggleClass() function** since all that comes to my mind was to first remove all the existing rotation classes on all questions and then add to the clicked one. Problem up there is it works all fine but I've added 0.5s of transition on each arrow and **when removeClass() fires it rotates back without transition**.

I've also **tried to create a rotate variable and add 360 degrees on each click**. But the rotation variable would stack on and on so that if you click on another question it rotates 360*n degrees for the first click. And also the arrows would stay looking up on click to another question.

I've may over-explained a bit but I've tried several methods that some people may suggest and I want to eliminate those.

Comment: _"and when removeClass() fires it rotates back without transition"_ - then you probably simply added the `transition` property in the wrong place ...? If you only added that to the elements _via_ this class - then they will of course not have any `transition` set, when you remove that class.

Comment: @CBroe that pretty much was it... I've never thought it was that simple. Apparently there was no need to complicate things. Thank you very much :)